# How to count the number of nodes with a certain name using the PugiXML?

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I'm using the PugiXML library in a C++ project and I have the following structure in an XML file. How can I count the number of `Plan` nodes?

```
<Profiles>
    <Plan>
        <Name>Foo</Name>
    </Plan>
    <Plan>
        <Name>Bar</Name>
    </Plan>
</Profiles>
```

Comment: What of <https://pugixml.org/docs/quickstart.html> you did not understand?

Comment: @ÖöTiib It looks like counting by iterating is an option. I'm actually looking for a one-liner solution.

Comment: `doc.select_nodes("//Plan").size()`.

Comment: @Botje Why do we need the double backslash?

Comment: Because that's how XPath works. The [pugixml documentation](https://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#xpath) has some pointers to XPath reading material.

Comment: @Botje I tried it and realized that when a double backslash is used, it finds all the matching nodes in the current file. Without a double backslash, it finds the number of matching nodes in the calling node. Thanks anyway.